# rotating Graphics/ image in c#

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, rotation

I have the following code which i wrote to try and rotate a bitmap(this is a test) the idea is to take a bitmap and rotate it by some amount of degrees and then draw it on the screen using win forms

```
protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDoubleClick(e);
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(path);
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        imagePosition = Cursor.Position;
        b = RotateImage(b, 45);
        g.DrawImage(b, new Point(100, 100));
    }
    public Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap b, float angle)
    {
        Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height);
        returnBitmap.SetResolution(b.HorizontalResolution, b.VerticalResolution);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);
        g.TranslateTransform((float)b.Width / 2, (float)b.Height / 2);
        g.RotateTransform(angle);
        g.TranslateTransform(-(float)b.Width / 2, -(float)b.Height / 2);
        g.DrawImage(b, new Point(0, 0));
        return returnBitmap;
    }
```

this is the image before rotation
    [image]

and this is the image after rotating 45 degrees like was shown in the code
    [image]

Comment: What's the problem? Is it that the image is getting clipped?

Comment: i think so, but i dont know why

Comment: i didnt understand the question at first, yes the problem is the image getting clipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's getting clipped is that there isn't enough space to display it rotated. The diagonal is longer than the sides (Pythagoras).

You need to make more space for the image, then it should display OK. How you do that will depend on what the image is contained in.